# How do you write a script for a music clip?

Tags: creative-writing, scene, lyrics

How do you write a script for a music clip? I am wondering because you need to sync the lyrics with the descriptions of the scenes, so I am wondering how it's done by the industry. Is there any standard, or people just do whatever they can to get their ideas across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would write it almost as if you are writing a subtitle file for a video, combined with a stage production technical script.

[Timestamp] - Lyrics - Notes

This way it is clear what you want going on, what lyrics are being sung/spoken at this point, and how far in to the scene this particular action/movement/whatever is taking place

For example

> [1min 12s] - Actor a singing "la la la la la" - Actors A + B are dancing, background is ......, lighting is .....,